# Why does this save the same input in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

So the code that is included saves a file based in the input given by the user and to make it a little better i decided to add an 'Add' button that is gonna create another 3 textinputs now i learned how to access them with id but it only saves the inputs in first 3 textinput boxes, i tried with a loop because i thought that when you took it the second time it might take the second input from the second 3 textboxes, but it didn't work.Ps sorry if the code is inefficient in some ways this is my first time making an app
this is the py file

```
from datetime import date
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

t=1
lista=[]
class MyGrid(GridLayout) :
    id_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    id_2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    id_3 = ObjectProperty(None)
    id_4 = ObjectProperty(None)
    id_10 = ObjectProperty(None)


    def add(self):
        self.ids.parts_text_inputs.add_widget(Factory.PartsTextInputs())
        global t
        t += 1

    def perfundo (self) :
        file = open('D:\\agron\\testing\\' + self.id_1.text + '-' + str(date.today()) + '.txt', 'x')
        global lista
        global t
        for i in range(0, t) :
            lista.append(self.ids.parts.ids.txtinp1.text)
            lista.append(self.ids.parts.ids.txtinp2.text)
            lista.append(self.ids.parts.ids.txtinp3.text)
        file.write('Emri dhe mbiemri :' + self.id_1.text + '\n' + 'Lloji i vetures :' + self.id_2.text + '\n' + 'Nr. i telefonit :' + self.id_3.text + '\n' + 'Problemi :' + self.id_4.text+ '\n' + 'idk :' + str(lista))
        file.close()



class HAZApp(App) :
    def build (self) :
        return MyGrid()


app = HAZApp()
app.run()
```

and this is the kv file

```
<PartsTextInputs@BoxLayout>:  # this is a rule for building the parts TextInputs
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    spacing: 20
    TextInput:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 48
        id:txtinp1
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        TextInput:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 48
            id:txtinp2
        TextInput:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 48
            id:txtinp3
<MyGrid>
    id: HAZ
    id_1: emridhembiemri
    id_2:llojiivetures
    id_3:numriitelefonit
    id_4:problemi
    id_10:add
    # rows: 10
    cols: 1
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'foto.jpg'

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.4,0.5,0.8,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Label:
            font_size: '40sp'
            outline_color: 0, 0, 0
            outline_width: 2
            text: 'Auto Servis "Haziri"'

    BoxLayout:
        spacing:10
        Label:
            text:"Name"
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1
        Label:
            text:"Type of car"
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1
        Label:
            text:"Phone number"
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1
        Label:
            text:"Problem"
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1

    BoxLayout:
        spacing:20
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id:emridhembiemri
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id:llojiivetures
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id:numriitelefonit
        TextInput:
            font_size: 20
            id:problemi

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 20
        column:2
        Label:
            text:'Parts'
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:'price for parts'
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1
        Label:
            text:'price for work'
            font_size: 20
            color:0.4,0.5,0.8,1

ScrollView:
    size_hint_y: 3  # Since this is part of a GridLayout space is assigned by size_hint ratios

    BoxLayout:
        id: parts_text_inputs  # this will contain all the parts TextInputs
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        PartsTextInputs:# this is the first of the parts TextInputs
            id:parts

BoxLayout:
    Button:
        id:add
        text:'Add'
        on_press:root.add()

BoxLayout:
    column:4
    Label:
        text:''
    Label:
        text:''
    Label:
        text:''
    Label:
        text:'Total'


BoxLayout:
    column:4
    Label:
        text:''
    Label:
        text:''
    Label:
        text:''
    Button:
        text:'total'

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text:''
    Button:
        text:'Finish'
        font_size: 20
        on_press:root.perfundo()
        on_press: app.stop()
    Label:
        text:''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the same output  because the `parts` id is only assigned to the first `PartsTextInputs` (the one that is originally in your `kv`). So looping through that same object multiple times will just repeat the same data. You can access all the `PartsTextInputs` by looping through the children of the `BoxLayout` with the `id` of `parts_text_inputs`:

```
def perfundo (self) :
    file = open('D:\\agron\\testing\\' + self.id_1.text + '-' + str(date.today()) + '.txt', 'x')
    global lista
    global t

    # get the list of all PartsTextInputs
    parts_prices = self.ids.parts_text_inputs.children[:]

    # reverse the list to get them in the samee order that you see on the screen
    parts_prices.reverse()

    # loop through all the PartsTextInputs
    for ti in parts_prices:
        lista.append(ti.ids.txtinp1.text)
        lista.append(ti.ids.txtinp2.text)
        lista.append(ti.ids.txtinp3.text)
        
    file.write('Emri dhe mbiemri :' + self.id_1.text + '\n' + 'Lloji i vetures :' + self.id_2.text + '\n' + 'Nr. i telefonit :' + self.id_3.text + '\n' + 'Problemi :' + self.id_4.text+ '\n' + 'idk :' + str(lista))
    file.close()
```